# Laravel - Logs are constantly recreated in the /public folder

Tags: laravel, laragon

Kinda having a weird problem here. I am using laragon as my local dev app and now I am testing my code on a shared hosting. The thing is, the laravel.log file puts itself and recreates itself in the /public folder if I delete it. I have absolutely no clue why.
It doesn't behave that way locally, only on the host.

Edit 1:

I am running Windows 10 and webhost is on Debian / Linux 8.11

Edit 2:

When I run a search in my vs code project, I only get two results for the indicated path.

One in the root of the project *laravel.log* and one in the *storage/logs* folder. The same file name.

[image: Root of site]

Comment: Have you specified custom log path in your config?

Comment: Nope, I don't know how to set that, the default storage/logs path suitted me well. @mrhn

Comment: Why would the webhost (running linux) include `D:...` in the path. It looks like either bad config or you accidentally uploaded your local cached config to the server

Comment: That's what I am asking myelf @apokryfos . I am sure it's bad config, but not sure where it comes from... I ran all the commands from php artisan to clear the cache though before uploading :/

Comment: Is it just logs that are saved like that or it happens for other files too? Plus save some files in public storage, see what happens. I had the same problem.

Comment: Happy to see I am not the only one! It's just the log folder. I will try your tip @MHIdea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that its related to symbolic link which can be different in windows and Linux. You can read more [here](http://file:///C:/MyWebSites/laravel8x/laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem.html#the-public-disk). As is shown in question link is created in windows, as an absolute path, which doesn't exist on Linux. One workaround would be to use relative paths in config/filesystems.php.

But the correct way is to include symbolic links in gitignore. Then in deployment you must run:

```sh
php artisan storage:link
```

to generate them according to the OS. You can add that command in composer.json ,  scripts->post-autoload-dump.

**UPDATE**

Laragon doesn't create an isolated environment like docker does. So when Laravel caches the config, it resolves the paths according to windows absolute path( here it's *D:\laragon\www...* ). As is mentioned in comments this Laravel app is moved to host using ftp without caching config on host. So host is using the same cache as windows.

Comment: Actually, I never used symlink in this projects. I don't have any public files I would like to show and there is nothing in the "storage/app/public/" folder except .gitignore

Comment: pls clear cache and config, and regenerate it on linux, see what happens.

Comment: Sure, just to be clear, what do you exactly mean by "regenerate it on linux"? 
Running clear cache and config and then transfer the project with .env modified or only transfering ressources and running composer on linux server and not locally?

Comment: run php artisan config:clear( and cache:clear) then php artisan config:cache on linux. Just to make sure laravel resolves paths in linux.

Comment: Have done this, it seems to not recreate itself for the moment :D

Comment: you can also,on linux, check bootsrtap/cache/config.php to check if there is any windows path in it. But the point is that this dir by default is also in gitignore!!!!

Comment: Is this relevant if I am not using git? If I recall correctly gitignore only ignores if I using git for deployement right? I am transfering via FTP

Comment: That's what I thought and was afraid of. You're not using ci-cd or git. You can't just move laravel between different OSs. Pls check bootstrap/cache/config.php (at least on windows). You will see many paths are resolved based on windows absolute path which means it doesn't work on Linux.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's where the error probably came from. I watched some tuts and laravle deployement section, didn't see git mentionned nor the cache thing. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You're welcome. You can try wsl or docker instead of laragon

Answer (score 0):

You probably defined the `APP_STORAGE` in your .env file to `D:\laragon\XXXXXX`.

You can comment out (using "#") that configuration variable and create a storage directory on the website root (at the same level of public directory).

Comment: I checked but I don't have it in there. I only have APP_NAME, APP_ENV, APP_KEY, APP_DEBUG and APP_URL